# Are we able to add pins to android home screen from HTML?

Tags: javascript, android, html, widget

I noticed a feature from Google recently, whereby if you Google a live sports game [you're able to follow it](https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/08/06/google-automatically-pin-live-score-future-matches/). Following the game adds a small widget to your home screen, where you can see the results.

I'm wondering: does Android offer APIs to do something similar? I want to be able to have a website which shows the scores of games, and allow a user to pin a widget to their home screen so they're able to view the games live.

Is this possible?

Comment: I was able to do this by turning my site into a progressive web app.
If your website has everything of a pwa (essentially a manifest.json in the root folder and a service worker), then Google Chrome will allow your users to pin the site to their home screen.As far as I know, they can only do this if they access your website using Google Chrome on Android though.
You can visit [this link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/#0) for more info.
[This video](https://youtu.be/mbkJqeNAbtY) shows what I mean.

Comment: Hi @Musevarg, I think you have misunderstood the question. I am not referring to saving a shortcut to a website to the home screen, but a widget that is able to pull data from an API and display football scores to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to this, and I would like to know the answer to this myself.
This is what we're talkin' bout:

[image: The soccer score is pinned to the home screen]

I tried the following in order to investigate:

- Open Chrome
- Open chrome devtools (F12)
- In DevTools, click the tripple dot on the top-right -> More tools -> Network conditions
- In the Network Conditions panel, switch the User-Agent to **Chrome - Android Mobile**
- In Chrome itself, search for WK 2021

[image: Pin live score]

- When you navigate to this element, you can see the HTML behind the button

[image: HTML behind the pin score button]

```
<div jsname="s2gQvd" class="EDblX DAVP1" jsslot="">
    <div class="imso-li-w">
        <popout-match-bubble-button jsaction="trigger.sbTXNb">
            <a href="https://search.app.goo.gl?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id%3Dcom.google.android.googlequicksearchbox%26utm_source%3Dbbl_aweb&amp;al=googleapp://deeplink/?data%3DElYKBgjusbuPARIDCLwFGi0SKwgIEifqxZ2_BiGymLLQBhsIAhIRCg0vZy8xMWZxODk2c2cwEAIYvt4EIAEiGAoWaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ&amp;afl=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id%3Dcom.google.android.googlequicksearchbox%26utm_source%3Dbbl_aweb%26url%3Dgoogleapp://deeplink/?data%253DElYKBgjusbuPARIDCLwFGi0SKwgIEifqxZ2_BiGymLLQBhsIAhIRCg0vZy8xMWZxODk2c2cwEAIYvt4EIAEiGAoWaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ&amp;apn=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&amp;amv=300865774&amp;utm_source=bbl_aweb" class="rb3KboTS9ex__link">
                <div class="rb3KboTS9ex__popout-container rb3KboTS9ex__click-target rb3KboTS9ex__popout-flat-border">
                    <span>
                        <svg class="rb3KboTS9ex__popout-icon" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M19 7h-8v6h8V7zm2-4H3c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 1.98 2 1.98h18c1.1 0 2-.88 2-1.98V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 16.01H3V4.98h18v14.03z" fill="#1a73eb"></path>
                            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                    <div class="rb3KboTS9ex__popout-text">Live score vastzetten</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </popout-match-bubble-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's very likely that the href does the trick, and you need a native android app (in this case `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox`) that handles the `Intent` that's being triggered by the url

```
https://search.app.goo.gl/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id%3Dcom.google.android.googlequicksearchbox%26utm_source%3Dbbl_aweb&al=googleapp://deeplink/?data%3DElYKBgjusbuPARIDCLwFGi0SKwgIEifqxZ2_BiGymLLQBhsIAhIRCg0vZy8xMWZxODk2c2cwEAIYvt4EIAEiGAoWaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ&afl=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id%3Dcom.google.android.googlequicksearchbox%26utm_source%3Dbbl_aweb%26url%3Dgoogleapp://deeplink/?data%253DElYKBgjusbuPARIDCLwFGi0SKwgIEifqxZ2_BiGymLLQBhsIAhIRCg0vZy8xMWZxODk2c2cwEAIYvt4EIAEiGAoWaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ&apn=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&amv=300865774&utm_source=bbl_aweb`
```